# How to test connection from GKE to MongoDB Atlas Server?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Theres a NodeJS application deployed on GKE

MongoDB Atlas Peering Connection is successful with GCP VPC Peering Connection

However, NodeJS Application is throwing error with connection with MongoDB

What can I do to test connection from GKE Cluster to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to deploy your nodeJS application and look at the application logs. If for some reason that's not working you could launch a mongo CLI pod, start a shell session and try to initiate the connection that way.

You mentioned the nodeJS application is throwing an error. You might want to copy paste that error here so people on StackOverflow can be of more help. It's important that you provide as much context as possible in your question.